# Local variable 'first' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

I get a *Local variable 'first' referenced before assignment* error when I run my code.

```
def start():

    global a
    a = [" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "]
    global first
    first = randrange(2)

    def reverse():

        if first == 1:
            first = 0
        else:
            first = 1

        if first == 1:
            turn = "X"
        else:
            turn = "O"
```

That is just a part of my code where the error occurs. However when I paste the code into IDLE it works no problem so I don't know why this is happening.

Anyways, my full code (unfinished Tic Tac Toe):

```
from os import name
from os import system
from random import randrange
from time import sleep




def cls():
    system(['clear','cls'][name == 'nt'])


def start():

    global a
    a = [" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "]
    global first
    first = randrange(2)

    def reverse():

        if first == 1:
            first = 0
        else:
            first = 1

        if first == 1:
            turn = "X"
        else:
            turn = "O"







    while True:

        reverse()
        cls()
        printBoard()
        print ""
        print "Its %s's turn." % (turn)
        print ""
        move = raw_input("Enter your move (1-9): ")

        if move.isdigit() == True:
            move = int(move)

            if move in range(9):
                move = move - 1
                if a[move] == " ":
                    a[move] = turn

                else:
                    print "Incorrect move: Place taken"
                    reverse()
                    sleep(2)    

            else:
                print "Incorrect move: Number out of range"
                sleep(2)    

        else:
            print "Incorrect move: Move not a number"
            sleep(2)







def printBoard():
    cls()
    print a[0],"|",a[1],"|",a[2]
    print       "---------"
    print a[3],"|",a[4],"|",a[5]
    print       "---------"
    print a[6],"|",a[7],"|",a[8]
start()
```

Comment: Where do you get the error? As In how do you run it when you get the error

Comment: In `def reverse():` you need to call `global first` again to access it. However, I would suggest against using globals and instead passing values as parameters to the functions.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function-other-than-the-one-that-created-them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python scans a function body for any assignments, and if they aren't explicitly declared `global`, then it creates a local scope variable for that name.  Because you assign to `first` in your `reverse()` function, and you haven't explicitly declared `first` to be global within that function's scope, python creates a local variable named `first` that hides the global one.

It doesn't matter that the assignment comes after the comparison; python implicitly declares all local variables at the beginning of the function.

To fix this you can declare `first` to be global within the `reverse()` function, but as others have said, globals should be avoided when possible.